# Android fatal exception unable to resume activity

Tags: java, android

[image]

Hi everybodi!

I'm new to Android programming and am trying to create a QR code reader app with Zxing. When I start my application in my phone, it gives me this error message. The app is started, after I push the button and then this is thrown... What is the problem?

Here is my code: This is the MainActivity

```
package com.example;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button scan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scan= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       if (requestCode == 0) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
             String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

             // Handle successful scan

          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
             // Handle cancel
             Log.i("App","Scan unsuccessful");
          }
     }
  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

And this is my AndoridManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:noHistory = "true"
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
           android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What is line 165 of your CaptureActivity?  You have NPE there.

Comment: need to add jar file.

Comment: viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);
and this is nullpointer!!! Which jar file?